# Sabre GDS Connector Java

Tags: automated-tests, sabre

Is there a Sabre GDS Connector api in java available to connect and send the commands to Sabre GDS and get the response? I need to automate the sabre commands output

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the sabre web services, the SabreCommandLLSRQ web service can be used to send commands within a sabre session.

Comment: Thanks and how can we get access to this webservice?

Comment: https://developer.sabre.com/home - but you need a contract with Sabre if you want to use it in production

Comment: Use sabre api for get all facilities like gds